# C# Async Task <IActionResult> return Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, actionresult

I am trying to make usage of the IActionResult interface to throw specific exceptions. But at this moment I am stuck at the controller.
I've written the following code to get a single call:

```
    [Route("singlecall")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(Models.CallModel))]
    [ProducesResponseType(404)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetSingleCall([FromQuery]string callId, [FromQuery] string token)
    {

        CallModel singleCall = await CustomerPortalBC.CallManagementBusiness.CallService.GetSingleCall(new Guid(callId), new Guid(token));

        if (singleCall == null){
            return NotFound();
        }

        return singleCall;
    }
```

This will (obviously) not work, because I cannot just return the singleCall object. It expects a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult. So I know exactly what the problem is, I only do not know how to solve it.

Any insight or help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to `return Ok(singleCall);`

Comment: Oh well, that was a easy solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

```
return Ok(singleCall);
```

Your object will be then proper HTTP result.

Answer (score 0):

You can also return a custom message.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   return Json(new { status = "error", message = ex.InnerException });
}
```